# Is there anyway to revoke links of files which is being shared with people MSFT in sharepoint online using PnP-Powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have many sites in my SharePoint tenant and in each site, I have many document library in each document library I have documents which is being shared with People in MSFT

[image]

Now I want to revoke links for sharing

[image]

is there any way to do that using PnP-Powershell

I tried using the following script but It takes too much which is not feasible as there are many documents in a document library

The Powershell script is as follows:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Interactive

$SiteURLs = @("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1" , "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site2")

Function Remove-OneDriveSharingLink($lists) {   
    process { 
        $Ctx = Get-PnPContext
    
    
        $Files = Get-PnPListItem -List $lists
        foreach ( $File in $Files) {       
            $Froles = $File.RoleAssignments
            $Ctx.load($Froles)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
            If ($Froles.Count -gt 0) {
    
                for ($i = $Froles.Count - 1; $i -ge 0 ; --$i) {   
                    $Link = $Froles[$i].Member
                    Write-Host($Link)
                    $Ctx.Load($Link)
                    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                    If ($Link.title -like "SharingLinks*") {
                        $Froles[$i].DeleteObject()
                    }
                    $Link = $null
                }  
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()           
            }      
        }
    
    }
}
foreach ($SiteURLs in $SiteURLs) {
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURLs -Interactive
    Get-PnPSite 
    $lists = Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 }
    foreach ($list in $lists) {
        Write-Host( $list.Title )
        Remove-OneDriveSharingLink($list)
    }
}
```